# Is the UNIX `time` command accurate enough for benchmarks?

Tags: linux, unix, profiling, benchmarking

Let's say I wanted to benchmark two programs: foo.py and bar.py.

Are a couple thousand runs and the respective averages of `time python foo.py` and `time python bar.py` adequate enough for profiling and comparing their speed?

**Edit:** Additionally, if the execution of each program was sub-second (assume it wasn't for the above), would `time` still be okay to use?

Comment: How long is the runtime of a single execution?  If it's less than a second, you'll probably have systematic error due to poor precision, and systematic errors won't be eliminated by averaging.

Comment: Well generally, code that I would profile in the first place would have much longer execution times than a second.

Comment: In addition, even if the intensive code had sub-second execution times, would performing that operation a million or so times *inside* of the program mitigate the systematic errors?  That way, `time` would be comparing a million runs of foo with a million runs of bar.

Comment: Agreed.  But e.g. a sub-second program called a hundred thousand times from a makefile or other shell script might be worth profiling, yet individual times would be meaningless.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`time` produces good enough times for benchmarks that run over one second otherwise the time it took `exec()`ing a process may be large compared to its run-time.

However, when benchmarking you should watch out for context switching. That is, another process may be using CPU thus contending for CPU with your benchmark and increasing its run time. To avoid contention with other processes you should run a benchmark like this:

```
sudo chrt -f 99 /usr/bin/time --verbose <benchmark>
```

Or

```
sudo chrt -f 99 perf stat -ddd <benchmark>
```

`sudo chrt -f 99` runs your benchmark in FIFO real-time class with priority 99, which makes your process the top priority process and avoids context switching (you can change your `/etc/security/limits.conf` so that it doesn't require a privileged process to use real-time priorities).

It also makes `time` report all the available stats, including the number of context switches your benchmark incurred, which should normally be 0, otherwise you may like to rerun the benchmark.

`perf stat -ddd` is even more informative than `/usr/bin/time` and displays such information as instructions-per-cycle, branch and cache misses, etc.

And it is better to disable the CPU frequency scaling and boost, so that the CPU frequency stays constant during the benchmark to get consistent results.

Comment: This is the most through answer, but what about cases in which program execution time is less than one second?

Comment: Thanks Chris. If it takes less than a second a large part of that time may be `exec()`ing the process. It's better to make a benchmark run over a few seconds to minimize start-up time bias.

Answer (score 63):

Nowadays, imo, there is no reason to use `time` for benchmarking purposes. Use `perf stat` instead. It gives you much more useful information and can repeat the benchmarking process any given number of time and do statistics on the results, i.e. calculate variance and mean value. This is much more reliable and just as simple to use as `time`:

```
perf stat -r 10 -d <your app and arguments>
```

The `-r 10` will run your app 10 times and do statistics over it. `-d` outputs some more data, such as cache misses.

So while `time` might be reliable enough for long-running applications, it definitely is not as reliable as `perf stat`. Use that instead.

*Addendum:* If you really want to keep using `time`, at least don't use the bash-builtin command, but the real-deal in verbose mode:

```
/usr/bin/time -v <some command with arguments>
```

The output is then e.g.:

```
    Command being timed: "ls"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1968
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 93
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 2
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 8
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

Especially note how this is capable of measuring the peak RSS, which is often enough if you want to compare the effect of a patch on the peak memory consumption. I.e. use that value to compare before/after and if there is a significant decrease in the RSS peak, then you did something right.

Comment: On Debian you'll need `linux-tools-$version` package.

Comment: On Ubuntu install `linux-tools-generic` (via [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50145/how-to-install-perf-monitoring-tool))

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `time` is accurate enough. And you'll need to run only a dozen of times your programs (provided the run lasts more than a second, or a significant fraction of a second - ie more than 200 milliseconds at least). Of course, the file system would be hot (i.e. small files would already be cached in RAM) for most runs (except the first), so take that into account.

<sup>the reason you want to have the `time`-d run to last a few tenths of seconds at least is the accuracy and granularity of the time measurement. Don't expect less than hundredth of second of accuracy. (you need some special kernel option to have it one millisecond)</sup>

From inside the application, you could use [clock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock), [clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime), [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday), 
[getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage), [times](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/times.2.html) (they surely have a Python equivalent).

Don't forget to read the [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) man page.

Comment: What is `time -d` ? I do not see that argument in the man page in linux or OSX.

Comment: I meant the adjective *timed*, with reference to the `time` command

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The time command gives both elapsed time as well as consumed CPU.  The latter is probably what you should focus on, unless you're doing a lot of I/O.  If elapsed time is important, make sure the system doesn't have other significant activity while running your test.