# Mac OS X Shell Script Measure Time Elapsed

Tags: macos, shell

How can I measure the time elapsed in milliseconds in a shell script in Mac OS X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using time command in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683434/using-time-command-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
start_ms=$(ruby -e 'puts (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i')
# do some work
end_ms=$(ruby -e 'puts (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i')
elapsed_ms=$((end_ms - start_ms))
echo "$elapsed_ms ms passed"
```

OR only shell builtins (works in bash and zsh):

```
start_ns=$(date +%s%N)
# do some work
end_ns=$(date +%s%N)
elapsed_ms=$(((end_ns - start_ns) / 1000000))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will be using the ruby approach because since I'm operating with Mac OS X the second approach doesn't actually work, but I'm curious if there is a way to measure milliseconds natively.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can the second approach for a shell-only method of measuring an interval.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `time` command ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/time.1.html)).  This will be much cheaper than invoking `ruby` just to tell you elapsed time:

```
$ time a_command
```

To "extract" the `real` time from the command do (untested):

```
real_time=$(time a_command | grep ^real | awk 'print $2')
```

(where `a_command` can be a shell function if necessary)

This will return the value in minutes and seconds, so if you want the result in milliseconds then use python (or your favourite scripting language) to run the process with timing functions around the outside of the sub-process invocation and you will not incur the *cost* invoking the scripting language just to get the current time.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787735/time-an-external-program-whose-output-is-being-processed-by-python) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701310/get-how-much-time-python-subprocess-spends) for details.

Comment: how can I do that in the shell? I want to get 'real' specifically, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

to calculate code execution inside your main shell script

```
START=$(date +%s) 

//you script like flutter build ipa

END=$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
echo "whole process finished in $DIFF seconds"
```