# wrk is displaying odd results on Rack vs Sinatra benchmark

Tags: ruby, sinatra, benchmarking, rack, wrk

I'm benchmarking a "hello world" equivalent using sinatra and rack.

Command in question `wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s`: 12 threads, 400 open HTTP connections, 30 seconds.

Rack:

```
require 'rack'

app = Proc.new do |env|
    ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['A barebones rack app.']]
end

Rack::Handler::Thin.run app

# wrk $ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://localhost:8080
# Running 30s test @ http://localhost:8080
#   12 threads and 400 connections
#   Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
#     Latency    11.82ms   38.97ms 488.51ms   99.32%
#     Req/Sec   705.04    568.62     2.20k    61.82%
#   16576 requests in 30.08s, 1.55MB read
#   Socket errors: connect 157, read 274, write 0, timeout 0
# Requests/sec:    551.05
# Transfer/sec:     52.74KB
```

Sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  status 200
  headers \
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html'
  'A barebones rack app.'
end

# wrk $ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://localhost:4567
# Running 30s test @ http://localhost:4567
#   12 threads and 400 connections
#   Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
#     Latency    40.12ms   90.46ms   1.39s    98.67%
#     Req/Sec   265.47    147.50     1.17k    73.15%
#   90322 requests in 30.08s, 18.78MB read
#   Socket errors: connect 157, read 333, write 0, timeout 0
# Requests/sec:   3002.52
# Transfer/sec:    639.21KB
```

Specs:

[image: test machine specs]

If both Rack and Sinatra run Thin, how come Sinatra manages 3002.52~ req/s while pure Rack manages only 551.05 req/s? What am I missing?

Comment: what's wrk? I've not heard of that command.

Comment: @iain https://github.com/wg/wrk

Answer (score 0):

I didn't install `wrk`, I wasn't in the mood for an install, but I ran both your examples using `time`:

```
# run.sh
for i in {1..1000}
do 
  curl localhost:8080/ > /dev/null 2>&1
done

# sinatra, run via `bundle exec ruby sinatra.rb -p 8080`
$ time sh run.sh             
sh run.sh  3.67s user 2.79s system 66% cpu 9.768 total

# rack, run via `bin/rackup config.ru`
$ time sh run.sh
sh run.sh  3.65s user 2.87s system 74% cpu 8.799 total

# sinatra with the puma server, by adding the line `set :server, "puma"`
$ time sh run.sh      
sh run.sh  3.67s user 2.71s system 92% cpu 6.924 total
```

I got very similar results, so perhaps it's something to do with `wrk` or your system. I'm running OSX Mavericks, but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006802/335847) that says to benchmark with `time` you should really use `chrt` to avoid contention with other processes. I'm not sure what the OSX equivalent of `chrt` is though. Perhaps that's what is happening on your system, or perhaps the ports are running at different speeds, for whatever reason.

I also sandboxed my gems using `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor.noindex`, perhaps that would have an effect on your system too.

Otherwise, I can't see any reason for such disparity. I a little surprised by the results I got as I'd expect Sinatra to be quite a bit heavier than Rack, but perhaps things seem different with more complex or larger apps. Or perhaps not, Sinatra is such a neat little library.