# Measuring performance difference between Python and Java implementations?

Tags: java, python, time, terminal, benchmarking

I want to compare the performance of two different implementations (Python and Java) of the same algorithm. I run scripts on the terminal (using Ubuntu 18) like this:

```
time script_name
```

I'm not sure how accurate this is. Is it possible to increase the accuracy of this benchmark? Perhaps there is a way to remove any restrictions or set-up in Python or Java?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866456/1358308 for an example in Python, there will be similar articles for other languages

Comment: note that if you use `time` to measure performance, you also measure the startup time of the jvm and the python interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006802), the correct way to benchmark a program using `time` is the following command:
`sudo chrt -f 99 /usr/bin/time --verbose <benchmark>`. However, note that this will only be accurate if the algorithm takes at least a second to execute, as otherwise the `exec` call might take up a big part of the benchmark.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26885810) suggests using `perf stat` instead, as such:
`perf stat -r 10 -d <your app and arguments>`.

Comment: Note mentioning that java vm has a 'warm-up' time during performance is bad. I'm not familiar with Python, but maybe it needs a 'warm-up' too. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1481853/6937584 for java vm

Comment: Well ideally, I'd suggest using a real benchmarking program, but this question was about how to use the `time` command.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of the `time` command is probably fine for most testing.

But if you wanted, you could write a 2nd Python script for timing with an `import subprocess` that then uses the `subprocess.call()` function (or one of several related functions in the `subprocess` module) to run the two versions of the algorithm.

Your timing script could also `import time` and then do `datetime.datetime.now().time()` before and after the algorithm runs, to show how much time passed.