# python program that terminates after one second

Tags: python, time, exit, sys

I want a piece of code that stops exactly in one second

**note** using `time.sleep()` does not do the job precisely

here is what I have so far(that doesn't give me precise result)

```
import time
import sys


start_time = time.time()

time.sleep(.99483-(time.time() - start_time))
print(time.time() - start_time)
sys.exit(0)
```

also note that the final time should include the last line which is `sys.exit(0)` execution

 I appreciate any help or advice you could spear

Comment: How precise it should be? Milliseconds, microseconds, tens of nanoseconds?

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski as precise as it can get

Comment: You expect microsecond [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9006596/14277722) when measuring with `time`? Please include the code to measure the time you're interested in.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I don't think I quite got what you've said I want a way to optimize the code above so that it terminates at exactly one second I also measured it with that print line in the code with python but it also gives me inaccurate results no matter what

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import sys


start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < 1:
    pass
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Try this and let me know if this meets your requirement

Comment: thanks for answer I've tried that solution before and it gives a result of slightly bigger than 1 but I want it to give something like 0.99999... as precise as it could be